# How do I configure skip_if on Twilio Taskrouter Workflow

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm developing Twilio Taskrouter.

I cannot configure skip_if on console and also Update API.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-presence

I tried Update API, response JSON has skip_if.

But, console JSON has no skip_if.

How do I configure skip_if?

Thank you @philnash.
My codes are below.

```
   public function test_retrieveWorkflow()
    {
        $account_sid = "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        $auth_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);

        $workspace_sid = "WSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        $workflow_sid = 'WWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $workflow = $client->taskrouter
            ->workspaces($workspace_sid)
            ->workflows($workflow_sid)
            ->fetch();

        $configurations = json_decode($workflow->configuration, true);
        $filters = $configurations['task_routing']['filters'];
        foreach ($filters as &$filter) {
            foreach ($filter['targets'] as &$target) {
                $target['skip_if'] = 'workers.available == 0';
            }
        }

        $configurations['task_routing']['filters'] = $filters;
        $configurations = json_encode($configurations);
        $workflow = $workflow->update(['configuration' => $configurations]);
        var_dump($workflow);
    }
```

Sorry,I forgot to write expect result.
Before, execute above code.

```
{
"task_routing": {
    "filters": [
        {
            "targets": [
                {
                    "queue": "WQyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
                    "expression": "task.email==worker.email",
                    "timeout": "10"
                },
                {
                ...
                }
            ],
            "filter_friendly_name": "filter by email",
            "expression": "1==1"
        }
    ],
    "default_filter": {
        "queue": "WQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

After, execute above code, result is expected JSON.

```
{
    "task_routing": {
        "filters": [
            {
                "targets": [
                    {
                        "queue": "WQyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
                        "expression": "task.email==worker.email",
                        "timeout": "10",
                        "skip_if": "workers.available == 0"
                    },
                    {
                    ...
                    }
                ],
                "filter_friendly_name": "filter by email",
                "expression": "1==1"
            }
        ],
        "default_filter": {
            "queue": "WQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

But, my twilio console shows before execute JSON.

Comment: When you say "I cannot configure skip_if on console", where are you trying to configure it? It should be in the `targets` of the `workflow`.

Comment: What have you tried exactly? Can you include the code you're using and the results that you expect?

Comment: Thank you @RobDiMarco.
I tried to configure task_routing > filters > targets > skip_if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TaskRouter PM here. I've updated the docs for this feature, which should answer all your questions:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-presence

(it won't currently show in the console in either view - see note in docs)

Comment: Thanks, I understand these features;)